# NPM not working when changing node version

Tags: node.js, npm, spfx

I have multiple node versions installed using nvm. currently when using node version 16.13.0 I can use npm with no issues but When I change the node version using [nvm use] to another version for example 14.16.1 I don't seem to be able to use npm.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFDKU.png)

I tried reinstalling npm but that didn't work. Anyone know what causes this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uninstalling 'npm-cache' folder.
If you're windows user you can find it in 'C:/Users/Name/AppData/Roaming'

Now uninstall node from 'Add or Remove Programs' from windows settings.

Open cmd installed node version using nvm

```
nvm install 14.16.1 
nvm use 14.16.1
```

Hope this will work !

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling and reinstalling 14.16.1.

```
nvm uninstall 14.16.1
nvm install 14.16.1
nvm use 14.16.1
npm ls -g --depth=0
```

If that doesn't work, can you try another version of Node or does this happen for every version?

Also, is this Nvm for Windows?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, yes on Windows and this happens for every node version except version 16.13.0. I also tried what you suggested but got the same message.